# Kafka: configuration by partition or by topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I created a topic in my kafka cluster with the following command.

`/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper kaf1:2181,kaf2:2181,kaf3:2181 --create --topic mytopic --partitions 10 --replication-factor 2 --config retention.bytes=1074000000 --config delete.retention.ms=6000 --config segment.bytes=105000000`

So, if I understand correctly the documentation, I have a topic with 10 partitions replicate 2 times beetween my 3 kafka hosts.
Next, each kafka host must retain 1Go of data. Each segment has a size of 100Mo and all old logs will be delete after 1 minute.

Now, when I do a `du -h` on my logs directory on a kafka hosts, I have this:

`1,2G       ./mytopic-2
1,1G    ./mytopic-8
1,2G    ./mytopic-9
1,1G    ./mytopic-6
1,1G    ./mytopic-3
1,1G    ./mytopic-0
1,2G    ./mytopic-4
7,6G    .`

I thought get 1Go for the directory entirely and not for each partition.

So my question is simple, the topic configuration is for each partition or for the all topic ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, see the picture below (distribution of partitions by the cluster nodes might be different):
[image]

Comment: Ok so the configuration topic is by partition and no by topic. Thanks for your answer. Do you have a link on the doc (I didn't find it) where it's explained ?

Comment: There is a section Topic-level configuration (3.1 - Broker Configs) that contains mapping between console tool configuration parameters and server properties. For example, retention.bytes parameter in console is equal to log.retention.bytes in server configuration, that is an amount of data to retain in the log for each topic-partitions. Please, see more details by the link:http://kafka.apache.org/081/configuration.html